# How to format number in pandas plot table?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data that I can plot using pandas plot command. I can plot a bar chart with a table, using this `plotdata.plot(kind='bar', colormap='gnuplot', ylabel = 'Yield', xticks=[], table=True)`. But I cannot figure out how to format the numbers in the table.
[image]

I tried to use the `applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)` in the command.
`plotdata.applymap('{:,.2f}'.format).plot(kind='bar', colormap='gnuplot', ylabel = 'Yield', xticks=[], table=True)`
But then all the data in the dataframe are strings and pandas cannot plot anything.

Error:
`no numeric data to plot`

I tried to google the problem but cannot find something.

Comment: have you tried using round(x,2) ?
You can either round your floats before doing the plot (but it's less accurate obviously), or finding a way to format the displayed content.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. `plotdata.round(2).plot(kind='bar', colormap='gnuplot', ylabel = 'Yield', xticks=[], table=True)`